# menu tab highlighting issue in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

views.py

```
def edit_report(request, report_id):
    """Edit report navigation from action needed screen
    """
    user = request.user
    if 'report_id' in request.session:
        del request.session['report_id']
    try:
        member = Members.objects.get(member=user)
        account_user = member.user
    except:
        account_user = user.id
    request.session['report_id'] = report_id
    request.session['account_user'] = account_user
    return redirect('incident.views.new_report')
```

template.html

```
<td class="irlist-num"><a href="{% url incident.views.edit_report list.report.id%}">{{list.report.incident_number}}{%if list.report.is_draft%} DRAFT{% endif %}</a> </td>
```

Now,when a new report is created using New Report tab,that tab will be highlighted.

The above view is for editing a report.In template,if the user clicks the report name link(`{% url incident.views.edit_report list.report.id%}`),it will takes the user to edit that particular report.Since this report is open under New Report Tab, New Report Tab is highlighted.I want to customize this to not highlight while open a report via this edit_report.

I am thinking to validate it using session in report_id,so if this report_id is in session the New report menu should not highlight,but i updated the tried code ,still it doesn't worked for me.Need help

Thanks

Comment: this is already asked yesterday

Comment: Hi,i want to check that this session is available in this edit method and don't highlight the new report menu.How to do this.

Comment: I am thinking to validate it using session in report_id,so if this report_id is in session the New report menu should not highlight,but i updated the tried code ,still it doesn't worked for me.I am not sure of doing like this but i tried this still not working.Need help to do this.

Comment: Can any one give me a solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code for the `new_report` view, it looks like it must be loading the correct report info based on `session.session['report_id']`. I think rather than passing things like that around via the session, you should probably just pass it as an argument to the `new_report` view when you call [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#s-redirect) (see link for django docs on redirect). Note that you'd also have to edit your view definition doing this.

Better yet, combine `edit_report` and `new_report` into a single view, if you've got almost all of the edit functionality in `edit_report` already.

Anyway, back to the question being asked. You can check if the report_id is set in you session in the `new_report` view (I assume you're doing this already). Then based on this, you can pass a variable in a `RequestContext` to your template

### Views.py

```
def new_report(request):
    view_template = loader.get_template('template.html')
    if 'report_id' in request.session:
        highlight_new_report = True
    else:
        highlight_new_report = False
    view_context = RequestContext(request,{
        'highlight_new_report' : highlight_new_report
    })
    return HttpResponse(view_template.render(view_context))
```

Then wherever the menu is in your template (note that this could very likely be in a base template being extended by `your_template.html`), you can use this to decide what class to add to the tab/link. There is probably something there already adding a class to highlight it, you should be able to override this based on the `highlight_new_report` variable which is now available in your template

### template.html (or a template template.html extends)

```
<!-- Menu tabs -->
<a href="/new_report" 
    {% if highlight_new_report %}
        class="highlighted_tab">
    {% endif %}
</a>
```

## Edit for more info

Sorry should have been clearer. The above code is an example of how you can set the class based on your `report_id`, but I left it unspecific because I didn't know what your template would look like.

If you've used the above code to add a CSS class which **removes** the highlight, then you can add another class which will **add** a highlight:

#### template.html (or a template template.html extends)

```
<!-- Menu tabs -->
<a href="/new_report" 
    {% if highlight_new_report %}
        class="highlighted_tab"
    {% else %}
        class="non_highlighted_tab">
    {% endif %}
</a>
```

Where `highlighted_tab` is a class which adds a highlight, and `non_highlighted_tab` is one which doesn't, or which overrides a highlight styling already being applied.

The reason I didn't write the answer this way to begin with, is because you probably already had something like `class="active"` being added based on the current page. So I expected you to use a condition like that above, to restrict the addition of this `active` class to when `highlight_report = True`

Comment: I've edited the answer with a bit more info. It's a little rushed, but hopefully it makes sense and will help.

Comment: Ciaran Philips,new_report and edit_report are two different method,so if i click the edit report it takes me to edit_report method and redirects to new_report method.So can you tell me in this way how to handle this.In question i was posted the edit_report method and new_report method is too lengthy not posted.More thing is session is created in new_report method and used in all pages,even now for edit also i am using the same session.

Comment: Yeah using the two methods (with a redirect from `edit_report` to `new_report`) is fine. There may be better ways but that will work. And your session handling is correct. The important thing now is just to add a conditional to your template like I've shown above. You said you've already used this code to stop the menu item from being highlighted when `highlight_new_report` is `True`, so you're nearly there, you just need to have an `else` in the condition to handle the case when `highlight_new_report` is `False`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do using session.

By seeing this bit of code,i understand that you are creating a session for new report.But what you are trying to do is not possible to handle with the same session.

I think,for new report and edit report their are two different methods.If this is the case its easy to handle.

Let us see this,

1.You should create a session in edit report method.

2.Should validate,whether that session is in new report,if that newly created session is in new report should set new_report=False and pass to render.

3.You should delete that newly created session in new report method,if not then menu will always be not highlighted.

As per the above one,if the user clicks report from `{% url incident.views.edit_report list.report.id%}` or edit report menu,the newly created session gets started from edit report method and will be available.

Hope this gives you an idea.